# MYSQL query to exclude column with null value in the result

Tags: php, mysql, null

The scenario is I have two tables that I wanted to query using a search function using PHP. There are two tables, table_a and table_b. In table_a it has id, name, middle_name, surname, case_no columns and table_b is similar. Data in table_b are all imported from another source, while table_a data was inserted manually by the users. There were instances that there is a duplicate data from table_a and table_b. What I want is to remove the duplicate data from table_b. Let say that in table_a there is a column which have null value, what I want is to exclude that from the result.

```
+----------+----------+----------+     +----------+----------+----------+
| name     | surname  | case_num |     | name     | surname  | case_num |
+----------+----------+----------+     +----------+----------+----------+
|  john    |  wick    |  1434    |     |  john    |  wick    |  null    |
+----------+----------+----------+     +----------+----------+----------+
      table_a                                  table_b
```

What I did now is create a view and combine the two together using Union. It will now look like this.

```
+----------+----------+----------+     
| name     | surname  | case_num |     
+----------+----------+----------+     
|  john    |  wick    |  1434    |     
+----------+----------+----------+ 
|  john    | wick     |  null    |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Now what I want is to query this table and to show only the result that has no null value which is

```
+----------+----------+----------+     
|  john    |  wick    |  1434    |     
+----------+----------+----------+
```

And if it is possible to automatically delete the row that has null value which is

```
+----------+----------+----------+     
|  john    |  wick    |  null    |     
+----------+----------+----------+
```

But the first problem is excluding the row that has null value from the result. Here is my query.

```
SELECT * FROM created_view_table WHERE name LIKE ? OR surname LIKE ? OR case_num LIKE ? AND 
case_num <> null;

SELECT * FROM created_view_table WHERE name LIKE ? OR surname LIKE ? OR case_num LIKE ? AND 
case_num IS NOT null;
```

Whenever I search for '%john%' it always show both row , the one with the column that has null value and the one that has not. If possible I only want to only show the result that has no null value.

Comment: Try with this ```SELECT * FROM created_view_table WHERE (name LIKE ? OR surname LIKE ? OR case_num LIKE ?) AND 
case_num IS NOT null;```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **or** **clause** so you need to bracket out the queries with **or** and try to do below

```
select * from created_view_table WHERE (name LIKE ? OR 
surname LIKE ? OR case_num LIKE ?) AND  case_num is not null;
```

This will solve your issue.

Comment: hey can I do a follow up question? What if I only want to exclude a column with a null value if it has duplicate? Like in the example they are both 'john wick', so they are duplicate and I exclude the one with null value. If the scenario is that there are two 'john' but different surname, one is 'john wick' and the other is 'john mcclane', but 'john mcclane' has a null value, but I dont want to exclude him.

Comment: as i can understand, you want to exclude null columns with duplicate columns only, but if name and surname are different then don't want to exclude?

Comment: yes, if possible, in the code above , if i query '%john%' it would exclude 'john wick' that has null value and only show 'john wick' without null value, but what if there is another entry another  'john' but this time its surname is 'macclane' which is different than 'wick', so it is not duplicate, but 'john macclane ' has a null value, so the query exclude him in the result, is there a way it wont be excluded, because it has no duplicate in another table?

Comment: to elaborate further, 'john wick 1434' is in table_a, and 'john wick null' is in table_b, so we exclude 'john wick null' because, first it is null and second it has duplicate in table_a, which is 'john wick 1434'. But what if there is another 'john' which is 'john macclane null' in table_b, also null, but different surname and has no duplicate in table_a. In our query it would be excluded because it is null, is there a way that it would only be excluded, if it has duplicate(similar name and surname, in a sense similar person) in table_a?

Comment: furthermore, I am thinking, I created the VIEW table using UNION, I read that UNION can remove duplicate? is that right and how? my query for creating view is "CREATE VIEW created_view_table AS SELECT name, surname, case_num FROM table_a UNION SELECT name, surname, case_num FROM table_b;"

Comment: what you want is a bit complecated in mysql query, you can do it after fetching data from mysql by using php. this would be peaceful.